# How to validate a token in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a method like this:

```
private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // Check if the token was issued by the server and if it's not expired
        // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date =  calendar.getTime();
        Query q = em.createQuery("Select u from User u where u.token = :token");
        q.setParameter("token", token);

        User uu = (User)q.getSingleResult();
        long diff = date.getTime() - uu.getTokenExpires().getTime();
        long diffMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
        System.out.println(diffMinutes);

        if (!uu.getToken().equals(token) || diffMinutes > 2) {
            System.out.println("Token is invalid");
        }
    }
```

And a method that authenticate a user:

```
public User authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        // Authenticate against a database, LDAP, file or whatever
        // Throw an Exception if the credentials are invalid

        Query query = em.createQuery("Select u from User u WHERE u.username = :name and u.password = :password");
        query.setParameter("name", username);
        query.setParameter("password", password);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();      
    }
```

This is the method used to generate the token:

```
private String issueToken(String username) {
    // Issue a token (can be a random String persisted to a database or a JWT token)
    // The issued token must be associated to a user
    // Return the issued token
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    return token;
}
```

How to validate a token, how to know if a token is expired or not - a token is expired after two minutes?

Comment: You did not make clear your problem. Please check [here](http://xyproblem.info/) and clarify your question.

Comment: I don't get it. You say JWT will be used... JWT solves all the requirements.